# Negation of statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, boolean-algebra

W(x): x is in the world

B(x): x is bad

From these two I form the statement, 'Something in the world is bad', given by $\exists x(W(x) \wedge B(x) )$

Now I want to write the negation of this statement, but i'm confused which one would be correct.

Would the negation be $\forall x \neg (W(x) \wedge B(x) )$ or would it be $\forall x W(x) \implies \neg B(x)$ ?

Comment: These two are equivalent statements, since $p \Longrightarrow \neg q \equiv \neg p \vee \neg q$ and $\neg(p\wedge q) \equiv \neg p \vee \neg q$

Comment: how did you arrive at the first equivalence relationship?

Comment: Construct a truth table for both expressions. You should see that they are identical.

Comment: @user140161 - Pay attention to the parentheses. Your second formula should be $\forall x(W(x) \to \lnot B(x))$.

Comment: In addition to being equivalent, the simplest form is just $\neg \exists{x}(W(x) \land B(x))$

Comment: @bames I suppose I could use a truth table to verify this relationship but what I meant was, how exactly did you arrive at this result? Is it a standard relationship that should be memorized? If so, does it have a name? Or did you derive it using other identities?

Comment: This is a standard result, yes. I don’t believe it has a special name.

Comment: @user140161 the equivalence $p \rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow \neg p \lor q$ is known as Implication

Answer (score 1):

> Would the negation be $∀x¬(W(x)∧B(x))$ or would it be $∀xW(x)⟹¬B(x)$?

Indeed.    Well, almost.   Do not drop the bracketting.

$$\begin{align}&\neg \exists x~\big(W(x)\wedge B(x)\big)&&\text{There is not something in the world that is bad.}\\\equiv&&&\text{(via quantifier duality)}\\&\forall x~\neg\big(W(x)\wedge B(x)\big)&&\text{Everything is not both in the world and bad.}\\\equiv&&&\text{(via de Morgan's rule)}\\ & \forall x~\big(\neg W(x)\vee\neg B(x)\big)&&\text{Everyting is not in the world or it is not bad.}
\\\equiv&&&\text{(via implication equivalence)}\\&\forall x~\big(W(x){\implies}\neg B(x)\big)&&\text{Everything, that is in the world, is not bad.} \end{align}$$